# Cannot find Mesh: Relax

Tags: mesh, add-on

I have blender 2.82, and when I go to edit >> preferences >> add-ons, I can't find Mesh: Relax at all. Keep in mind I'm a total beginner :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to activate another add-on: `Add-ons->Edit Mesh Tools`.

How I understand `Relax add-on` include in `Edit Mesh Tools add-on`. This problem was discussed at [the bug tracker](https://developer.blender.org/T78315).

Though the official manual tells us another information:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/edit_mesh_tools.html#
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/relax.html

Maybe the developers didn't correct information in the manual.

[image: Activate add-on]

[image: Get result]

[image: Get result]

Answer (score 0):

Mesh > Relax is not an addon.

Use the search function (f3) to find Relax, it is included by default

Comment: It isn't there, though.  It claims it's included by default, but it isn't.  Doing an F3 search for relax on version 2.90.1, for me, brings back relax from looptools only, which is more specific in use than the generic mesh relax myself and the original poster are looking for.

Comment: No indeed. You need the Looptools addon activated in Preferences. Relax will then show on the Right-click > Looptools submenu.

Comment: Found it! You do need to enable an addon to see the original Relax menu item. - It's under Mesh: Edit mesh tools in the addons. Then select a vertex or two and use the Vertex > Relax entry at the bottom of the menu. You'll also see two Relax entries under F3 search although there's no way of telling them apart there. It's the same both in 2.83 and 2.9 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as the original poster. As you can see in the attached screenshots, Relax shows up neither in Add-ons or search. The manual says it should be in addons: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.83/addons/mesh/relax.html. This is on Blender 2.83.1 on Windows.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you searching with F3 in Edit mode? You won't find it if you're in Object mode!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't show up in Edit Mode either (on Blender 2.83.6). The search box shows no results.

Comment: Very odd. I't certainly there on my machine under 2.83.7. All I can suggest is reinstalling Blender.

Comment: I've just installed 2.83.8, and _still_ this doesn't show up on search or addons, neither in object mode nor in edit mode with a mesh selected, and I've tried it in faces, vertices and edges submodes. I don't even need it any more but I'm still very confused as to why it's not showing up!

Comment: As per @JohnEason's suggestion, just tried a fresh install of Blender 2.90.1 on a different machine (both machines are Windows 10), and still I can't Relax :-) It doesn't show up for me in addons or in search, in object or edit mode, despite the manual saying that the addon is included by default https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/relax.html?highlight=relax